# Where should I put the throws InterruptedException for the sleep function in java

Tags: java, interrupted-exception

I've looked up where to put it and all I'm getting are mixed answers and the purpose of this is to create rudimentary for the alpha version of this game. Here is the code:

```
public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("OK, That looks perfect");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Huh, What's that");
    }
}
```

I know that there is no `throws InterruptedException`. I'm just wondering where to put it.

Comment: If you are coding and working with java you must need to know about exception handling and different methods to throw an exception.

Comment: What do you think i'm trying to do

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it in the `throws` clause on the `main` method. If you are certain that the sleep will not be interrupted, this is the best option.

```
public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("OK, That looks perfect");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Huh, What's that");
    }
}
```

You could also catch it if it requires handling.

```
public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("OK, That looks perfect");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            //handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Huh, What's that");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this i.e. Adding `throws` keyword in the method signature itself which will pass the exception to the calling method:

```
public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("OK, That looks perfect");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Huh, What's that");
    }
}
```

Or

Use something like i.e. `Try-Catch` blocks to handle that exception then and there only:

```
public class Intelijence {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("OK, That looks perfect");
            try {Thread.sleep(5000);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
            System.out.println("Huh, What's that");
        }
    }
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: Just `e.printStackTrace()`. Not `System.out.println(e.printstacktrace)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` throws an `InterruptedExcpetion` - you need to either `catch` it, or declare a `throws` clause in the method the calls it - in this case, `main`:

```java
public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Here ---------------------------^
        System.out.println("OK, That looks perfect");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Huh, What's that");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary options

1. declare that main throws interrupted-exception
2. just put try { } catch () {} around the sleep statement, and enter a short error message stating something like "Should never get here"

Comment: I should point out that this is really a design decision - what does the OP **want** to happen if the sleep is interrupted?  (1) hand the decision over to someone else? (2) ignore the exception? The two aren't exactly equivalent.  [In this case the second seems appropriate]